# Apache mod_deflate only for files larger than 1000 bytes

Tags: apache-2.2, http, httpd, mod-deflate

Is it possible to use mod_deflate in Apache 2.2 only for files bigger than a certain size ?

According to this [article](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#GzipCompression) and common sense only files over 1000 bytes benefit deflate/gzip.

Answer (score 4):

There is no directive like that for mod_deflate as you can read up here: [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html). There has been an option like this with mod_gzip.